# view a dynamic php site locally -from a php newbie

Tags: php

Complete PHP newbie question here,

I'm trying to load up locally a dynamic PHP site, but i get an error. I'm using EasyPhp 12.1.
the error message is:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'User'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\site 2\includes\includes.php on line 3
Failed to connect to mysql database.
```

I should add that i got instructions for accessing the site, and these were:

1. import the database (how do i do this? to where?)
2. edit includes/config.php

Comment: looks to me like you don't have a MySQL DB running locally

Comment: theres a database called build.db, is that what I want?

Comment: sorry, build.sql*, containing table names and contents

Comment: No, that is something else. MySQL is a database management system, a server that has to be installed, configured and run on your system. The file build.sql most likely holds the descriptions how to setup the tables required by your appliciation. That has to be fed into your database server.

Comment: Have you installed MySQL on your machine? if not [here you can get the MySQL server](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/)

Comment: I haven't installed mysql. So, i should install that, and then i can 'load in' build.sql?

Comment: @user1870307: I'm sorry, but if you have no idea of how to configure anything, might I suggest you _RTFM_ before asking why you can't connect to something you don't know how to set up? Just download it, and just have a look at the docs... there are a lot of tuts and step-by-step guides out there. If you get stuck somwhere down the line, _then_ you can ask a question here

Comment: It looks like `EasyPHP` comes with MySQL and PhpMySqlAdmin pre-packaged. Look around in EasyPHP's interface for a link or button to take you to the MySQL administration tool.

Comment: Elias: Thats not nice mate. I'm not being lazy, i genuinely am lost here. What manual am i meant to read when I don't know what program to use?
Sean Quinn: Thanks man, I think I have it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't use EasyPHP for local development (I use [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)) EasyPHP appears to be a very similar package. If the local site you are trying to view does not include a PHP-driven install script for setting up the tables by pointing to a particular database instance, then you will have to manually load the tables using the SQL interface. If you have not already set up the database, you'll also have to do this. Also, you may need to configure username and password access. All of this can be done from within the PhpMyAdmin interface packaged with EasyPHP.

To reach it, first I would look at EasyPHP's administration interface. There is probably a link or something that will take you to the MySQL admin tool. Here you can manage and configure all of your MySQL databases, including creating database table space that the local site will use.

Once the database is created, in order to import the database, it really depends on how it was given to you. If it is an `.SQL` file, you can probably just run it from within the PhpMyAdmin interface on the database instance you've created.

This can all be done using other SQL tools (e.g. command line), but if you're new to working with databases, PhpMyAdmin is probably a good place to start.

Finally, in your config you'll probably have to specify:

- hostname (e.g. localhost)
- port (e.g. 3306)
- database name (whatever name you gave the instance)
- username (e.g. root)
- password (e.g. root)

So that it can properly connect to your database.

When in doubt, consult documentation and setup instructions for EasyPHP (and MySQL). Also, if you're very new at working with PHP and database, you might also try setting something like [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) up locally or some other nicely written piece of PHP software so that you can get a little more familiar with the initial set up process for databases, etc.

Comment: hey thanks man, that's really helpful. So I don't currently have MySql installed but am installing it now. also going with xampp instead of easyphp because it seems more straight forward. I think i follow your instructions, will repost if i get lost!

Comment: ok, so have run into some difficulty (inevitably, right? :P)
I'm in the PHPmyadmin, created a database, and imported the build.sql file. I still get the same error. I created a username and password for that database and added it to the config file for the site.

Comment: Don't know what more advice to give; It sounds like you're still keeping with EasyPHP from one of your other comments. Are you using the MySQL that was bundled with EasyPHP or one you set up separately? The error seems to be generated from the includes.php, line 3 which, I am assuming is making the connection to the MySQL database. Take a look at that file and see what it is passing across for your database information, including credentials. Make sure that everything is lining up.

Comment: Another suggestion might be to try replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` (they are synonymous, one is just the alias the other the IPv4 address, while IPv6 is `::1` for localhost)

Answer (score 0):

Well, waht does the error message tell you?

You script has no permission or ability to access the database server it is meant to. This has nothing to do directly with php or the page, it is a question of how you setup your mysql server. You *did* configure a local database server, didn't you? That won't happen my magic...

Comment: honestly man, I don't know how to do that. my knowledge of databases are limited to microsoft access interacting with visual basic, and my knowledge of web design is limited to static content. I thought that by installing EasyPhp that acted as the server for the entire site, what should i do instead?

Comment: I have no idea about what 'EasyPHP' is, but maybe consulting its documentation helps?

Comment: arkascha, easyphp is just a package- through it i'm using PhpMyAdmin and created the database in there. I'm still getting that message, and have double checked the account settings in my config file. where can i look to from here? i also double checked the name of the database is correct etc

Comment: Simply try to connect from the command line using the same credentials as stored inside your application and as shown in the error message. Most likely that fails. Then think about why. Note that MySql has an own internal permission system like any other database management system. You have to setup the right permissions in there. There are endless documents about that in google.